# Unity C# setting initial position and moving on dice roll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trudging along learning Unity 2D and have branched out to see if I can create a Monopoly type game.  I have the board, tokens and dice setup.  I found examples of dice rolls and moving online and have been trying to adapt them.  Currently I am stuck in setting the two tokens on the initial waypoint (0) and while I can click the dice and see the "roll" of the die, no movement happens.  I am hoping someone can show me where I am going wrong and what I am missing.

GameControl.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject whoWinsTextShadow, player1MoveText, player2MoveText;

    private GameObject player1, player2;

    public int diceSideThrown = 0;
    public int player1StartWaypoint = 0;
    public int player2StartWaypoint = 0;

    public bool gameOver = false;

    private int whosTurn = 1;

    private FollowThePath player1Piece;
    private FollowThePath player2Piece;

    void Awake()
    {
        whoWinsTextShadow = GameObject.Find("WhoWinsText");
        player1MoveText = GameObject.Find("Player1MoveText");
        player2MoveText = GameObject.Find("Player2MoveText");

        player1 = GameObject.Find("Player1");
        player2 = GameObject.Find("Player2");

        player1Piece = player1.GetComponent<FollowThePath>();
        player2Piece = player2.GetComponent<FollowThePath>();

        player1Piece.moveAllowed = false;
        player2Piece.moveAllowed = false;

        whoWinsTextShadow.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        player1MoveText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        player2MoveText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void MovePlayer(int steps)
    {
        switch (whosTurn)
        {
            case 1:
                 StartCoroutine(player1Piece.Move(steps));
                 break;

            case -1:
                StartCoroutine(player2Piece.Move(steps));
                break;

        }

        whosTurn *= -1;
    }
}
```

Dice.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] diceSides;
    private SpriteRenderer rend;
    
    Vector3 initPosition;

    public int diceValue;

    public GameObject gameControllerGameObject;
    private GameControl gameController;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameController = gameControllerGameObject.GetComponent<GameControl>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        diceSides = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Graphics/Dice/");
        rend.sprite = diceSides[5];
        initPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RollTheDice());
    }

    private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {
        int randomDiceSide = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            randomDiceSide = Random.Range(0, 6);
            rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }

        diceValue = randomDiceSide + 1;

        gameController.MovePlayer(diceValue);

    }
}
```

FollowThePath.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowThePath : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public Transform[] waypoints;
    public bool isMoving;

    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed = 1f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int waypointIndex = 0;

    public bool moveAllowed = false;

    public IEnumerator Move(int steps)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        isMoving = true;

        while (steps > 0)
        {
           waypointIndex++;
           transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
           waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position,
           moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

           yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);

           steps--;
        }

        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need debug statements to see what’s going on

Comment: I have been debugging this and it gets to gameController.MovePlayer(diceValue); in the Dice.cs but doesnt kick off the MovePlayer code.

Comment: Well we don't see your `MovePlayer` code ... How is your first code related to the second one?

Comment: And in general there is a big flaw in your `Move` of the second code: this will barely move at all! You want to smoothly move **until** (second inner while loop!) you reach the waypoint, then go to the next .. currently you move a single timy step towards it, then go to the next waypoint and move a single tiny step towards that one etc

Comment: @derHugo The MovePlayer code is in GameControl.cs which calls Move in FollowThePath.cs.